# How to name boxplots?

Tags: r, label, rename, boxplot

I've created 3 boxplots in R which have been labelled as, `1`,`2` and `3`. How do I change these labels?

I tried,

```
names = 1(20/21 Cohort), 2(19/20 Cohort), 3(Individual)
```

But the code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

what is the code you created the boxplots with?

you could use sth. like that: (package: ggplot2)

```
    ggplot(data =df, mapping = aes(x,y, color=df$... ))+
geom_boxplot()+
...
```

with color=...you can set colors automatically by each different entry of a column. So your legend should work
if you want to create names for a complete plot use the lab function and add:

```
labs(title = "your title")+
```

to your ggplot

Comment: boxplot(CO1920mine$`Cardiac Output 20/21 (ml/min)`, CO1920mine$`Cardiac Output 19/20 (ml/min)`, CO1920mine$`Individual Cardiac Output (ml/min)`, names = 1(20/21 Cohort), 2(19/20 Cohort), 3(Inidividual Cardiac Output))